# How to make image fit to viewport scale

Tags: html, css

I`m sorry that I can not bring a perfect meaning to the title.
You can test code at http://dainielhhong.com/page1.html

I want to make crack and box fit regardless of the size of screen.

It fits in my monitor, but crack goes up or down when I change the size of screen.

```css
.parent-container{
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 2vh;
  width: 67vw;
  height: 85.81vh;
  border-top: 2px black solid;
  border-left: 2px black solid;
  border-right: 2px black solid;
}
.container{
  display: flex;
}
.item:nth-child(1){
  flex: 1;
  height: 28vh;
  border-right: 2px black solid;
  border-bottom: 2px black solid;
  font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;

}
.item:nth-child(2){
  flex: 2.6;
  height: 28vh;
  border-bottom: 2px black solid;
  font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;

}
.item:nth-child(3){
  flex: 1;
  height: 28vh;
  border-left: 2px black solid;
  border-bottom: 2px black solid;
  font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;

}

img{
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: -50%;
}
```

```html
<div class = "parent-container">
  <div class = "container">
    <div class = "item"></div>
    <div class = "item"></div>
    <div class = "item"></div>
  </div>
  <img src="http://dainielhhong.com/page1.html">
</div>
```

I think problem comes because svg size is so big, but I don`t know what the exact problem is.

Comment: You could draw the vertical lines on the image directly and make sure the content of SVG is aligned with the bottom. Simple CSS positioning will solve remaining problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is the concept of responsive images.

Refer to link below to overcome your query

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images

Comment: This is not an answer!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow Harshith Raj. These kind of *reference to study* links are more suitable to be posted as a comment not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS fix

```
img{
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: -50%;
  position: Fixed;
}
```